# Запятые при уточняющем обороте

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли выделять запятыми оборот "вместе с..." в предложении:

> Кроме собственного производства созданы развитая логистика и маркетинг, что(,) вместе с современными информационными технологиями и интернетом(,) позволяет обеспечить быстрое и качественное выполнение практически любого заказа и любой номенклатуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме собственного производства**,** созданы развитая логистика и маркетинг, что вместе с современными информационными технологиями и интернетом позволяет обеспечить быстрое и качественное выполнение практически любого заказа и любой номенклатуры.

Я бы так расставил. Уточнения там нет.
А что такое "выполнение номенклатуры"?

Answer (score 2):

Розенталь называет такие конструкции обособленными дополнениями и дает возможность выделить их запятыми, хотя это не очень строгое требование.